# newline after heading while using <h3> tag in android

Tags: android, html

Recently I was trying out HTML tags in android. When I tried to use the `<h3>` tag, it automatically creates a line space after it and before the next line. In HTML one can remove it by making padding and margin set with 0px. Can anyone tell me how can I remove this space in an android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default rendering of `h3` has top and bottom margins, and you can remove the bottom margin easily in CSS:

```
h3 { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

I don’t see anything Android-specific here, but just to be sure I tested this on Android, and it works as expected.

If the next element after the heading is a `p` element, then that element has a top margin by default. To remove it, you would add

```
h3 + p { margin-top: 0; }
```

(Does not work in rather old versions of IE, but I wouldn’t care.)

Comment: Thanks.. Actually i wanted something inline..so that i can just directly use settext method of textview :-                                                                       String text = "<h3><font color='red'>Html.fromHtml</font></h3>"
+ "<i>The would appear in italics.</i>"; view.setText(Html.fromHtml( text));

Comment: Is there a way so that i can do this inline?..Can you show me an example?

Comment: You can do it inline, too, though that’s mostly much clumsier (e.g., you would need to repeat the code for each and every `h3`). Example: `<h3 style='margin-bottom: 0'><font color='red'>Html.fromHtml</font></h3>"`.

Comment: Actually I tried this one but it doesn't seem to work for me. Can you please try the inline way and tell me if it worked for you?

Comment: so is it the problem because I gave minsdkversion = 8?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to add the margin trick you use normally in this context too. :) It will probably work.

Comment: can you please show me an example. I tried margin but it didnt work for me:(

Comment: the same way you would do it in the browser
like: 
<h3 style="margin:0; padding:0">Sub titel</h3>

Actually never done this before. Another sugestion is using a <p> and giving it the style you want for example bigger text etc